# Scirpting AutoIT to read username and password from file

Tags: google-app-engine, autoit

I'm scripting AutoIT to read username and passwrod from a file to make deployment less painful since otherwise I must provide username and password for each deployment. I'm a newbie with AutoIT and I just RTFM, the following is what I got and since I'm a newbie I'm certain that you can find something that I'm doing wrong, but the following is doing the job for me in a better way than was answered by this problem before:

```
Local $sLauncherPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe"

Local $iPid = Run($sLauncherPath)

Local $hWin
While ProcessExists($iPid)
    $hWin = WinWait("Deploy Application to Google", "", 1)
    Local $file = FileOpen("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\launcher\settings.dat", 0)

    Local $line = FileReadLine($file, 1)
    Local $line2 = FileReadLine($file, 2)

    If $hWin And WinGetProcess($hWin) = $iPid Then
        ControlSetText($hWin, "", "Edit1", $line)
        ControlSetText($hWin, "", "Edit2", $line2)

        ControlClick($hWin, "", "Button2")

        WinWaitClose($hWin)
    EndIf
WEnd
```

It seems to work for me, could you make possible improvement suggestions since this is only my 2nd AutoIT project?

Comment: Check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a question, but here is the answer you are looking for:

- The file opening and reading doesn't have to be inside the loop, so should be outside...
- ... Especially since you aren't closing the file (see the `FileClose` function)...
- On the basis I have no `settings.dat` I'm guessing that it is a file you've created. There should be some error checking for whether it exists or not.
- As a general rule user config files belong in the user directory, rather than Program Files. If you want to store your program in Program Files then look at using either %AppData% or perhaps even the registry.
- For config files, `.ini` have built in AutoIt support and are easier for humans to edit when you have lots of settings.
- Using `FileReadLine` and giving a line number is very inefficient when you are actually reading them sequentially (it will open the file up, go to the beginning, and count line feeds). Not really an issue on code this small, but you'd be better off without the last argument.

And finally it is spelt AutoIt with a lowercase 't' :P